# C# How to observe deeply nested hierarchical Objects?

Tags: c#, mvvm, nested, domain-driven-design, inotifypropertychanged

I am writing an C# mvvm app where I have one big Domain Model on the UI Layer that contains nested hierarchical objects. The big Domain Model object has many nested objects that all implement INotifyPropertyChanged. For now its OK to assume the big model is a Job and the Job gets filled with Data over its life cycle until it gets sent away. The Job gets manipulated during its lifetime and is a live entity object and not a simple value object (struct).

The root object itself is also observable via INotifyPropertyChanged and this causes two issues:

1. Observing an Object nested on Level 3 means that the observer/listener has to keep track of the whole big model by recursively adding event listeners up until to the root -> maintainability is low because every observer needs to know the whole big model up to its root. Changes to the big model result in changes to many different parts of the app.
2. Some Listeners are actually interested in different Levels of the object, for example a specific listener might want update from Level 2 and Level 4.

Ideas so far:

1. Expose a Factory (pattern), that knows the big Object and creates ObserverObject : IDisposable, for Listeners to be grabbed. That way a listener only has the ObserverObject and gets notified about value changes, while the factory performs book keeping to resolve the nesting and invalidation when higher levels get set to new values. This way i get the headache of the internals only at one point instead of many and provide better maintainability.
2. Every field and nested object and its field, and,... of the big model gets an Unique Adress in form of an Uri. A listener knows the Uri and asks a repository to receive an ObserverObject for the given Uri. This approach extends the first option in that it allows to have objects of same kind on different nesting levels which i ocassionally have.

I am not really sure which approach is better, but I am tending to the second option. In my use cases I will have different listeners that may be interested in different levels of the big model and additionally there are some dynamic Objects in Collections (items can be added and removed frequently and listeners need to react to that, e.g. updating lists in ViewModels)

Answer (score 0):

> C# How to observe deeply nested dynamic Objects?

Ideally you should not be using Dynamic the type or really types created at runtime. Disabling compile time type safety is bad. But dynamic can outright "infect" other types. If you use a Dynamic in part of a calculation, the return value of your Function becomes dynamic too. But I asume you considered all other options thorougly.

If you have to continue having dynamic types, consider the use of [ExpandoObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject). It seems directly made for this job. In effect it is little more then a `Dictionary<string, object>` with some Syntax sugar - and most importantly Change Notification according to INotifyPropertyChanged on all "Keys"/"Properties".

I do not quite understand what Deep nesting has to do with this. You need 3 types of change notification with any Collection:

- on every property of the Collection Item (ExpandObject or some concrete type).
- on every addition and removal of elements. That is the one ObservableCollection takes care of
- And on the property exposing the list. As OC is bad a bulk modifications, you often have to prepare a new list in code behind before exposing it to the GUI and binding.

As long as everyone follows those rules, you can next it however deep you want.

If you are worried about performance of this:

1. Read the [Speed Rant](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/), skip part 1.
2. You are retreiving too much data for the user to process anyway. My rule of thumb is to never exceed 100 fields/values thrown at the user. Ideally way less then that. Always do as much filtering, sorting and the like in the Query. Do not retrieve more data then the user can process. While MVVM has all those nice filter and sort options near the GUI, you should try to avoid them.

Comment: By dynamic I didn't mean the dynamic keyword. I meant that objects might be replaced dynamically at all levels of the big model. Even the big model itself might be invalidated by calling create new Job for example. I am not retrieving too much data, but I have to deal with hierarchical UI data (thats the nesting i meant) that is subject to change. Think of it like a big live UI Model where different viewmodels can subscribe to parts of it during runtime. I have to maintain a UI Model because it has to have different fields than the Logic Layer Model equivalent.

Comment: @DenisDik: If the big model can change, it should be exposed via a property of the Application ViewModel. ViewModels are pretty nestable by design. | I am confused about this term "UI Model". Do you mean teh ViewModel or the View?

Comment: In MVVM theres the Model, the View and the ViewModel. I was refering to the Model of MVVM when i wrote UI Model. An Example: ViewModelX observes a Collection that is a field of parent ObjParent. Another ViewModelA sets the ObjParent to null effectively invalidating the Collection that is observed by ViewModelX and ViewModelX shall immediately clear its Collection field. BUT: When a new ObjParent is set, ViewModelX shall be informed about a new Collection that it can subscribe to.

Comment: @DenisDik Again: Does "UI Model" mean "View", "ViewModel" or something else entirely? "UI Model" is not a term in MVVM. So I have issues understanding what you mean when you say it.

Comment: From msdn mvvm: Model classes are non-visual classes that encapsulate the app's data. Therefore, the model can be thought of as representing the app's domain model, which usually includes a data model along with business and validation logic. Examples of model objects include data transfer objects (DTOs), Plain Old CLR Objects (POCOs), and generated entity and proxy objects.

Comment: @DenisDik: Yes, that is the definition of the Model part of MVVM. How does this explain "UI Model"?

Comment: UI Model = MVVM Model. In my app I have kind of the same Model with variations in attributes in different Layers. For example the UI Model has fields like bool Selected, whereby the Logic Model is not concerned about Selections of its Entities (Reference type objects).

Comment: @DenisDik That still is not making sense. Sorry, but if you invent your own terminology, no communication can happen. MVVM is a design pattern. It's letters stand for "Model", "View" and "ViewModel" (the order is a bit messed up, but that is historically grown). "UI Model" does not exist in this.